# Open API version 3.1 samples request (json)

Tags: openapi

Dear Stack Overflow users,

I am trying to understand the 3.1 version of the specification. Even though the online spec is clear, examples always help. It would greatly help to have access to examples in json format of online API's.

If anyone can point me to existing API's on version 3.1 hat would be appreciated

Regards, Sam

Answer (score 0):

https://apis.guru have a large collection of OpenAPI definitions in JSON and YAML formats. Several are open (not needing authentication to use).

Comment: much appreciated, i was able to detect and fix a bug with these samples (for me test-data).